# Cocoa HTTP post method authentication

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Using below code I am trying to get result which should be like success or something else. But In my result value I am getting nothing, its blank.

What can be the issue?

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

    NSString *user = [userName stringValue];
    NSString *passwd = [passwordField stringValue];

    NSLog(@"username:::password::: %@ %@", user, passwd);


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.html?userName=%@&userPassword=%@"];

    NSError *myError = nil;

    // create a plaintext string in the format username:password
    NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", user, passwd];

    NSString* encodedString = [[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];

    // create the contents of the header 
    NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", encodedString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  
                                                       timeoutInterval: 3];   

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // add the header to the request.  Here's the $$$!!!
  //  [request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request addValue:user forHTTPHeaderField:@"userName" ];
    [request addValue:passwd forHTTPHeaderField:@"userPassword" ];

    // perform the reqeust
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection  
                    sendSynchronousRequest: request  
                    returningResponse: &response  
                    error: &myError];  
  //  *error = myError;

    //the content of the webserver's response.
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] length:[data length]];

    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);

}
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your URL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.html?userName=%@&userPassword=%@"];
```

This is not correct.

dont you need to add here the user and password? Something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.html?userName=%@&userPassword=%@", user, passwd];
```

And.. why are you creating the strings like that? Instead of:

```
NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", encodedString];
```

You should do:

```
NSString *authHeader =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", encodedString];
```

I really think your problem is in the strings you are creating, check all of them

Comment: I have checked it, it says in NSLOG "Request: <NSMutableURLRequest (null)>"

Comment: have checked your suggestion but still result value is empty

Comment: Your url is empty after creating it?

Comment: I edited with more info, Im pretty sure your problem is on the strings you are creating

Comment: I have checked in console my request shows: Request: <NSMutableURLRequest http://http://myurl.html?userName=szia&userPassword=szia>

Comment: So now your request is correct, if its still not working the problem should be on the server side